# Why can't I transfer my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-bank, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum, pokemon-black-white

I was transferring my Pokemon from Pokemon Pearl to Black, and from Black to Y. However it wouldn't transfer my Arceus, Giratina, or Darkrai. What happened?

Their names are GodDeer, GhostDrake, and Nightmare respectively - Were the names not allowed?

Comment: They are legit right? Also check for held items

Comment: Pokemon that have nicknames that aren't allowed will just have their nickname removed when transferred to bank. Could you give some more information on the error you received?

Comment: I suppose the problem is from Pokemon Black to Pokemon Bank? If so, I don't think you need these many tags, and can use the minimum of pokemon-bank.

Comment: Restating @IG_42's comment, it will not work if they are hacked or illegal pokemon.

Comment: Illegal  how? Also No more comments just answers.

Comment: @HenryRuiz - Can you take some pictures of the Pokemon summary screens? Specifically the 'Caught At' screen, the Original Trainer (OT) name/ids, and the Pokeball type?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you Pokemon are legal. I believe this answers your question. The following was taken directly from the [Pokemon Bank FAQ](http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-us/faq/):

> All the Pokémon that appear in Pokémon X, Pokémon Y, Pokémon Omega Ruby, or Pokémon Alpha Sapphire that can be deposited in Pokémon Bank. However, there are some Pokémon that you will find yourself unable to bring into Pokémon X, Pokémon Y, Pokémon Omega Ruby, and Pokémon Alpha Sapphire using Pokémon Bank and Poké Transporter.
>
> - Some Pokémon cannot be transferred from the GBA games Pokémon Ruby, Pokémon Sapphire, Pokémon Emerald, Pokémon FireRed, and Pokémon LeafGreen to the DS games Pokémon Diamond, Pokémon Pearl, Pokémon Platinum, Pokémon HeartGold, and Pokémon SoulSilver using the Pal Park feature.
> - Some Pokémon cannot be transferred from Pokémon Diamond, Pokémon Pearl, Pokémon Platinum, Pokémon HeartGold, and Pokémon SoulSilver to Pokémon Black, Pokémon White, Pokémon Black 2, or Pokémon White 2 using the Poké Transfer feature.
> - Some Pokémon from Pokémon Black, Pokémon White, Pokémon Black 2, and Pokémon White 2 cannot be transferred to Pokémon X, Pokémon Y, Pokémon Omega Ruby, or Pokémon Alpha Sapphire.
>
> Which Pokémon can or cannot be transferred depends on the settings of each game, so this information cannot be provided here. Please try transferring your Pokémon to confirm their eligibility for yourself.